# Pull specific xml node for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to pull a different `<node>` for each row in the table, the position of the node is stored in `SpecificNode`

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
        XmlValue XML,
        SpecificNode INT
    )

INSERT INTO @table SELECT   '<root><node>Y</node><node>Y</node><node>10</node><node>YARD</node></root>', 3
INSERT INTO @table SELECT   '<root><node>N</node><node>20</node><node>PART</node><node></node><node>PASS</node></root>', 2
INSERT INTO @table SELECT   '<root><node>Y</node><node>30</node><node>FORK</node></root>', 2
```

I can pull a specified node, but when I try to make it dynamic it give me the error "The argument 1 of the xml data type method "value" must be a string literal."

```
SELECT  
    XmlValue.value('(/root/node)['+SpecificNode+']', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @table AS tbl
```

Same error with this

```
SELECT
    x.value,
    XmlValue.value(x.value, 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @table AS tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT '(/root/node)['+CONVERT(VARCHAR, SpecificNode)+']' as value) X
```

My expected output would be

```
10
20
30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sql:column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx?ppud=4)

```
SELECT
  XmlValue.value('(/root/node[sql:column("SpecificNode")])[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @table AS tbl
```

Comment: This is perfect, is there any way to modify the column value here?  So say SpecificNode started at 0 instead of 1, is it possible to increment it?

Comment: I used a CROSS APPLY and selected the SpecificNode +1, just wondering if there is a better way

Comment: You can add one to the value pulled by `sql:column` in the xpath expression `sql:column("SpecificNode")+1`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

CREATE table #table
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY,
        XmlValue XML,
        SpecificNode INT
    )

INSERT INTO #table SELECT   '<root><node>Y</node><node>Y</node><node>10</node><node>YARD</node></root>', 3

INSERT INTO #table SELECT   '<root><node>N</node><node>20</node><node>PART</node><node></node><node>PASS</node></root>', 2

INSERT INTO #table SELECT   '<root><node>Y</node><node>30</node><node>FORK</node></root>', 2

declare @a varchar(1000), @IDENT INT;
declare @values as table (value INT)

SET @IDENT = 1

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR select
'SELECT
    XmlValue.value(''(/root/node)['+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SpecificNode)+']'', ''VARCHAR(100)'')
FROM #table AS tbl  WHERE ID = '

from #table

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @A

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

SET @A = @A + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @IDENT)

INSERT INTO @values(value)
    EXEC (@A)

```
SET @IDENT = @IDENT + 1

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @A
```

END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR

DROP TABLE #table
SELECT * fROM @values

Some additional efforts needed. First change table variable to temp table, then add ID column to the table with identity. The result will come in different resultsets. To get them all at one resultset,a table variable need to be created to store them.

Comment: This works but produces 3 separate result sets, and i'd like them in one result set and preferably not have to loop through the table